# ESPER using csv adapter with POJO

Tags: esper

I need some help with esper using csv files as input with csv adapter. I need to use POJO classes and more than 1 csv file.

If there is an example that includes the above with listener as well I will appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use Java objects as events ,simply register the event type name for the Java class and provide the same name to the CSV adapter.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.addEventType("Event1", Event1.class);
    configuration.addEventType("Event2", Event2.class);
    configuration.addEventType("Event3", Event3.class);


    epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);

    EPStatement stmt = epService.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(
       "select * from Event1, Event2,Event3");

    (new CSVInputAdapter(epService, new AdapterInputSource(filename1), "Event1")).start();
    (new CSVInputAdapter(epService, new AdapterInputSource(filename2), "Event2")).start();
    (new CSVInputAdapter(epService, new AdapterInputSource(filename3), "Event3")).start();
```